# How to use Instant Purchase in Magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.2, instant-purchase

I have read the release note of Magento 2.2.2 regarding an Instant purchase. But I would like to know more about it.

I know following details about this feature :

```
Instant Purchase feature allows the Customer to place the order in seconds without going through full checkout. Once clicked, the system places the order using default shipping and billing addresses and stored payment method. The order is placed and a customer gets a confirmation message in the notification area.

Prerequisites to display the Instant Purchase button:
Instant purchase enabled for a store at Store / Configurations / Sales / Sales / Instant Purchase
Customer is logged in
Customer has default shipping and billing address defined
Customer has valid stored payment method with instant purchase support
```

The question is how instant purchase support may be implemented for any payment method with vault support?

What are the steps we need to make Custom Payment Method compatible with instant purchase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find answers in the official documentation:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/mrg/ce/instant-purchase/
- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-instant-purchase.html

Example of payment method integration may be found in Braintree module:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2.2/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/InstantPurchase
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.2/app/code/Magento/Braintree/etc/config.xml#L74-L78

Comment: I have read those links already as mentioned in the question. I need some real time examples with explanation.

Comment: See updated comment. It is actually what is described in DevDocs under Payment method integration section.

Answer (score 0):

I have read detail of this feature and found that something important:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-instant-purchase.html

As per above doc please carefully read the line:

**Customer accounts have a stored payment method with vault enabled.**

As per above line we will require **vault enabled** for custom payment method.Hence it is required to **Adding vault integration** to save custom credit card information that will need in Instant Purchase.

More About Vault Integration Please refer to link:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html

So make Our Custom Payment Method compatible with instant purchase we will Require **Vault Integration.**